# JOptionPane.showMessageDialog Why it is ERROR?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class finals {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "";
        boolean test = false;


        text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a or b: ");

        for(int i = 0; i<text.length(); i++)
        {
            if(text.charAt(i) == 'a' || text.charAt(i) == 'b')
                {
                    test = true;
                } 

            else 
                {
                    test = false;
                    break;
                }
        }

        if(test == true) {

        text = text.replace("a", "o");
        text = text.replace("b", "1");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,text, "Tan awa :)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }

        if(test == false) {

----->  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DILI MAGPATAKA :)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: WHY this is ERROR GUYS? the ARROW one.

Comment: Because a parameter is missing. There should be 4 not 3.

Comment: Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: ohhh i forgot to put "" :) thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `title` (or possibly the `message` parameter)

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DILI MAGPATAKA :)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Should be more like....

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is some text", "DILI MAGPATAKA :)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

or some such, depending on what it is you are trying to say...

Answer (score 2):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"DILI MAGPATAKA :)",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

You are parsing 3 input argument to `showMessageDialog()`. There is no matching method for this in  `showMessageDialog()`.

Only following methods available.

```
showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,Object message)

showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int essageType)

showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,
    Object message, String title, int messageType, Icon icon)
```